# Showing Dialogs MVVM Pattern

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a property here that shows a selected message from a combobox. In my InitializeMessageFields method I load a datagrid based on the selected item.
 lets say I have differemt I items in my combobox. what I wanted to do is show (in some dialogbox) the selected  item before loading the grid to notify the user what grid data belongs to which item.
 private string _selectedMessageType;

```
    public string SelectedMessageType
    {
        set
        {
            if (_selectedMessageType == value) return;
            this._selectedMessageType = value;
            InitializeMessageFields();
            this.NotifyPropertyChanged("IsMessageTypeSelected");
        }
        get
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Loading ",_selectedMessageType );
            return this._selectedMessageType;
        }

    }
```

How can I do that?

Comment: [DialogBoxes in MVVM](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/70223/Using-a-Service-Locator-to-Work-with-MessageBoxes)

Comment: Slightly tangential to the question, but I would consider it bad practice for a property setter to open a dialog box.

Comment: Why my question down voted? would be nice if you comment when down voting it will help the user to learn from making the same mistake ?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you want to open the dialog box you could either raise an event in your view model, use the Service Locator pattern as Viv suggests, or use [MVVMLite's Messenger](http://blog.galasoft.ch/archive/2009/09/27/mvvm-light-toolkit-messenger-v2-beta.aspx) (just a few ideas).
You could directly open up your dialog box from your view model, but this is ***not advisable*** since it prevents you from unit testing your view model or reusing the view model (perhaps as a [portable class library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/gg597391%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

Here is an article and some sample code from msdn that shows how to open a wpf dialog.  You could pass in a ViewModel to your dialog constructor and set the window's data context.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969773.aspx#Custom_Dialog_Boxes

```
 // Instantiate the dialog box
 MarginsDialogBox dlg = new MarginsDialogBox();

 // Configure the dialog box
 dlg.Owner = this;

 // Open the dialog box modally 
 dlg.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 0):

Showing the dialog box directly in the VM makes testing difficult. Instead pass a service as a Dependency via the constructor that is responsible for showing messages. Implement it through an interface so you can mock it for testing.

Alternatively use something like the event aggregator in prism. This would be my preferred approach.

If for laziness you want to show directly in vm then at least add a Boolean property to  suppress for testing.